# Cordova Device and Application events

Tags: cordova, events, sleep, shutdown

I would like to listen on events such as Application closing and Device shut down to run some code (such as logout feature) before the Application closes or the Device shut down / sleep events.

Is this possible with Cordova/Phonegap? I looked for plugins and I found plugins about [PowerManagement](https://github.com/Viras-/cordova-plugin-powermanagement) related events but nothing about these events.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not able to listen on events like `onAppClose` nor `onDeviceShutdown` or `onExit` - **these events don't exist**.

There are events which can be triggered by adding an `eventListener` to your code.

### Example

**DeviceReady Eventlistener**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

The `yourCallbackFunction` will fire when your device has entered the `deviceready` state.

A Documentation about the eventListeners given you from Cordova/Phonegap can be found here:
[Cordova - Eventlistener Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html)

---

As BipBip said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31287197/3671726), that there could be a possibilty to trigger such events with the `onunload` attribute inside the `body` tag, i just tested that inside a clean cordova application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<!--        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">-->
<!--        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">-->
<!--        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="alert('onload fired');" onunload="alert('onunload fired');">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So `onunload` never fired (nor if you replace the `alert` with a `console.log()`) **because cordova apps** that get totaly closed will **never fire such events**.

An alternative to all of this behaviours could be the `onPause` eventListener. This one fires instantly after the user switches the application or taps the home button to get to the homescreen. That one gets implemented by:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPauseFired, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know about those standard cordova events. What I need is something (maybe a plugin) so that the app detects when the it is being closed down or Device shutting down to be able to do some clean up tasks such as log the user out.

Comment: As far as i know, there are no events or plugins which will trigger such events - sorry jimny :-/

Comment: you know the `onPause` eventListener jimny? Maybe that one is the one for you?

Comment: so the unload event is never fired?  Isn't the onPause the same as the pause event documented in the cordova documentation? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html

Comment: correct, it never fires and onPause is the same as the pause eventlistener - it is the pause eventlistener, i just call it onPause :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this links provide what you want about a Cordova life Cycle :

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.fr/2011/04/phonegap-lifecycle-events.html

*When you application exits the unload event is called.  This is a useful event if your application needs to save some state data. You would register your unload listener the same as you would for the load event by adding it to the body tag.*

```
<body onload="onLoad()" onunload="onUnLoaded()">
```

Comment: This would be totaly new to me - i'm going to test this in a clean cordova project. Just 5 Minutes.

Comment: For me too, I just discovered it , let me know :)

Comment: I'm going to edit the answer i made already and tell you, what i discovered - but it is not working.

Comment: Edited, hope this helps you BipBip! :-)

Comment: I can confirm that the onunloaded is never called :(